# Кнопки для остановки и возобновления работа дополнительного потока

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qthread

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатие кнопки **`стоп`** программа прекратила печатать цифры, а кнопка **`пуск`** стала доступной и при нажатие на неё программа начала печатать цифры заново.

Объясните на моём простом примере. Потоки в скрипте обязательны.

**untitled2.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushStop = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushStop.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushStop.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пуск"))
        self.pushStop.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "СТОП"))
```

**main.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

from untitled2 import Ui_MainWindow
import sys


class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ''' Потоковая задача '''
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)  # Объявляем сигнал, с аргументом(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(50):
            self.sleep(1)
            print(i)
        self.threadSignal.emit


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.thread = WorkThread()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

    def func1(self):
        # Создаем поток
        self.pushButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.thread.start()

    def on_finished(self):
        self.pushButton.setDisabled(False)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

from untitled2 import Ui_MainWindow
import sys


class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ''' Потоковая задача '''
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)  # Объявляем сигнал, с аргументом(int)   # <---

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(50):
            self.msleep(200)
#            print(i)
            self.threadSignal.emit(i)                                              # <---


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
# +++        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)  
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.pushStop) 

        self.thread = WorkThread()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_label)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

        self.pushStop.setDisabled(True)
        self.pushStop.clicked.connect(self.func2)   

    def func1(self):
        # Создаем поток
        self.pushButton.setDisabled(True)
        self.pushStop.setDisabled(False)
        self.thread.start()
#+++        
    def func2(self):
        self.thread.terminate()
        self.pushStop.setDisabled(True)
        self.pushButton.setDisabled(False)

    def on_finished(self):
        self.pushButton.setDisabled(False)
        self.pushStop.setDisabled(True)
#+++        
    def on_label(self, value):
        self.label.setNum(value)       


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()                   # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()                           # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]